# pgAdmin connecting using Kerberos throws error - No authority could be contacted for authentication

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4 version 6.10. I am facing an issue when connecting using Kerberos using my AD credentials. It throwing the error -

> 'Unable to connect to server: connection to server at 'xxx.xxx', port
> 5432 failed: SSPI continuation error: No authority could be contacted
> for authentication. (80090311)'

[image]

Note that I am able to connected to the server with username and password.

What could be the possible cause for this error?

Comment: Look in the server's log file to get its side of the story.